# Behavior of nested arrays in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this piece of code :

```
json = require('dkjson')
dataStr = "{}"

function addEntry(position, hour, id)

        local data = json.decode(dataStr) or {} 
        
        if not data.detections then
            print("create data.detections")
            data.detections = {}
        end
        if not data.detections[position] then
            print("data.detections[position]")
            data.detections[position] = {}
        end              
        if not data.detections[position][hour] then
            print("data.detections[position][hour]")
            data.detections[position][hour] = {}
        end
        table.insert(data.detections[position][hour], id)
                
        dataStr = json.encode(data)
        print(dataStr)
end

addEntry("toto", 28000, 11111)
addEntry("toto", 28000, 22222)
addEntry("toto", 28000, 33333)
addEntry("toto", 28000, 44444)
addEntry("toto", 28000, 55555)
```

And I have this output on Zerobrane :

````
create data.detections
create data.detections[position]
create data.detections[position][hour]
{"detections":{"toto":{"28000":[11111,11111]}}}
create data.detections[position][hour]
{"detections":{"toto":{"28000":[22222,22222],"28000":[11111,11111]}}}
create data.detections[position][hour]
{"detections":{"toto":{"28000":[33333,33333],"28000":[11111,11111]}}}
create data.detections[position][hour]
{"detections":{"toto":{"28000":[44444,44444],"28000":[11111,11111]}}}
create data.detections[position][hour]
{"detections":{"toto":{"28000":[55555,55555],"28000":[11111,11111]}}}

I would have expected to have this in the final string : 

```{"detections":{"toto":{"28000":[11111,22222,33333,44444,55555]}}}

Can somebody explain to me this Lua behavior ? The override instead of adding a new value, and this remaining separate first value ?
````

Comment: Replace `= {id}` with `= {}`

Comment: Start the body of `addEntry` with the following statement: `hour = tostring(hour)`

Comment: The tostring made it ! Thank you ! The {id} was a typo remaining from a if then else end I wrote just before copying the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [dkjson documentation](http://dkolf.de/src/dkjson-lua.fsl/home):

> It can also be used to save Lua data structures, but you should be
> aware that not every Lua table can be represented by the JSON
> standard. For example tables that contain both string keys and an
> array part cannot be exactly represented by JSON.

```
addEntry("toto", 28000, 11111)
```

prints

```
create data.detections
create data.detections[position]
create data.detections[position][hour]
{"detections":{"toto":{"28000":[11111,11111]}}}
```

You created and encoded the table

```
{detections = {toto = {[28000] = {11111, 11111}}}}
```

Which gives you the json string

```
'{"detections":{"toto":{"28000":[11111,11111]}}}'
```

When you decode this json string you'll have a lua table like

```
{detections = {toto = {["28000"] = {11111, 11111}}}}
```

As you see after decoding 28000 is now a string key and not the integer you encoded.

So when you call

```
addEntry("toto", 28000, 22222)
```

where hour is a number again, you'll end up with the table

```
{detections = {toto = {[28000] = {22222, 22222}, ["28000"] = {11111, 11111}}}}
```

that contains values for both the numberic and the string key.

If you encode this again you get the json string

```
'{"detections":{"toto":{"28000":[22222,22222],"28000":[11111,11111]}}}'
```

Now we decode this again leaving us with the table

```
{detections = {toto = {["28000"] = {11111, 11111}}}}
```

as the first `"28000"` entry `{22222, 22222}` is of course overwritten by the second one `{11111, 11111}` as we cannot have two elements for the same key.

Now the same thing happens for each of your following calls. You add a numeric key and lose it in the en/decoding process.

Numeric keys will only be used if your table is a sequence with consecutive integer keys from 1 to n. All other table keys are convertet to a string.

The double values are caused by the fact that you do this

```
 data.detections[position][hour] = {id}
```

When `data.detections[position][hour]` is `nil` which due to the problem described above is true in every call.

As you add id to the table after that you end up with a table containing the `id` twice. Create an empty table instead.